# How to decompose a square matrix into two non-square matrices?

Tags: matrices, optimization, matrix-decomposition

I want to know if there is any method that decomposes a square matrix into two non-square matrices. Most of the methods I've seen have square matrices, upper/lower triangular matrices(LU methods) or more than two matrices(SVD) as the end result. In particular, I am looking for matrix U such that

U'*U= A

where

```
A=[2 -1 -1
  -1  2 -1
  -1 -1  2]
```

U would be a 2x3 matrix in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only possible if $A$ is not full rank. In that scenario, a low-rank decomposition would be what you are looking for.
Conveniently, the SVD gives you one such low-rank decomposition. If you write out the SVD $A=USV^{T}$ as

$A=\sum_{k=1}^n s_{ii}u_i v_i^{T}$

where $u_i$ and $v_i$ are the columns of $U$ and $V$, and $s_{ii}$ is the corresponding singular value, then it becomes apparent that if any of the $s_{ii}$ are zero, the equality still holds even if that term is dropped. This corresponds directly to shaving off a column from $U$ and $V$ as desired. To get it down to two matrices, you can just take $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ diagonal matrix $S$ and find an appropriate square root of it $S^{1/2}$ (which is possible since $S$ has non-zero real values) and set the two factors as $M_1=US^{1/2}$ and $M_2=VS^{1/2}$. It will only be possible to make $M_1=M_2$ if $A$ is symmetric, in which case $U=V$.

Comment: That was enlightening! My matrix has a rank of 2, so we get U=2x3 . In general, for a nxn matrix of rank m, do we get a mxn matrix after SVD?

Comment: Are we considering S to be a (n-1)x(n-1) matrix because the rank here is n-1?    Won't M2 be S^(0.5)*V'?      And why is a symmetric A a condition for U=V? [I might be missing some trivial algorithm here]. In general, for matrices, AB=CB does not mean A=C. Why is U=V here?

Comment: Yes, I was just using $(N-1)\times (N-1)$ because the example was about removing a single term. If your rank is smaller you can remove even more terms. 
I'm taking $A=M_1M_2^T$ to match the SVD, thus the ordering of $M_2$.
If the matrix is symmetric, the SVD matches the [eigendecomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Real_symmetric_matrices) which is known to have that property for symmetric matrices.

Comment: That was informative. Between your answer and the other one, future readers will be benefited. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The SVD will give you the decomposition you want.  Simply, for a symmetric matrix, $A=U\Sigma U^T$.  Take only the columns of $U$ that correspond to the nonzero singular values in $\Sigma$ and multiply them by the square root of the corresponding element in $\Sigma$.  In other words:

```
> [u s v]=svd(A);
> i=find(diag(s)>0);
> B=(u(:,i)*diag(sqrt(diag(s)(i))))'
> norm(A-B'*B)
ans =    1.9117e-15
> B
B =

  -0.27236  -1.06564   1.33800
   1.38774  -0.92974  -0.45800
```

Comment: Is this Matlab Code? I forgot to add that the two rows were orthogonal, but your answer satisfies that!

Comment: Yup.  It'll work in either MATLAB or Octave.